# Should a <li> that contains a link have the same amount of padding if in a <nav> element?

Tags: html, css

**Intent**
To make links in a footer easier to click on when on mobile.

**Background**
I have a footer with links. The links were very close together and I wanted to make them easier to click on. When you see the footer on mobile, clicking the links was difficult.

Rather than adding a `margin-bottom` I chose to add padding to the `<li>`. But I also did that to the `<a>` because I wanted to add clickable area. I opted for `padding` as opposed to increasing the `font-size`. I tried just increasing the padding in the `<a>` element but not sure if that would make other links overlap each other.

---

Should I have the `<li>` and the a the same height? or maybe I should add `line-height` instead?

This is my current CSS

```
.footer-widgets ul li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}

.footer-widgets ul li a {
  color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
  padding: 3px 12px 3px 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the page showing the clickable area

[image: screenshot of links]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to your links, so they fill up the li elements. The li will expand with the a tag this way. You may need to set a width on your ul or li to prevent the links from going across the page.

Comment: Great suggestion. So I am thinking adding a `line-height` to the `<li>` and giving them a `max-width`. On this footer, I would not want the link to expand across the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the `<li>` and `<a>` the same height. I've used my mobile device on many pages with a similar setup as your own, including my own site. Most devices running Android 4.1+ have the optional functionality of click-zoom (the content is magnified when the browser cannot determine the exact element attempting to be selected). I don't use this feature personally, and smaller elements work perfectly fine.